# Run consul agent with config-dir caused not found exception

Tags: kubernetes, consul

In our docker-compose.yaml we have:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  consul-server:
    image: consul:latest
    command: "agent -server -bootstrap -ui -enable-script-checks=true -client=0.0.0.0 -config-dir=./usr/src/app/consul.d/"
    volumes:
      - ./consul.d/:/usr/src/app/consul.d
```

In the `consul.d` folder we have statically defined our services. It works fine with docker-compose.

But when trying to run it on Kubernetes with this configmap:

```
ahmad@ahmad-pc:~$ kubectl describe configmap consul-config -n staging
Name:         consul-config
Namespace:    staging
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
trip.json:
----
... omitted for clarity ...
```

and consul.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: consul-server
  name: consul-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: consul-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: consul-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: quay.io/bitnami/consul:latest
        name: consul-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8500
        #env:
        #- name: CONSUL_CONF_DIR # Consul seems not respecting this env variable
        #  value: /consul/conf/
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /consul/conf/
        command: ["agent -server -bootstrap -ui -enable-script-checks=true -client=0.0.0.0 -config-dir=/consul/conf/"]
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: consul-config
```

I got the following error:

```
ahmad@ahmad-pc:~$ kubectl describe pod consul-server-7489787fc7-8qzhh -n staging
...

Error: failed to start container "consul-server": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"agent -server -bootstrap -ui -enable-script-checks=true -client=0.0.0.0 -config-dir=/consul/conf/\": 
stat agent -server -bootstrap -ui -enable-script-checks=true -client=0.0.0.0 -config-dir=/consul/conf/: 
no such file or directory": unknown
```

But when I run the container without `command: agent...` and bash into it, I can list files mounted in the right place.
Why consul gives me a not found error despite that folder exists?

Comment: did you try http://kompose.io  conver your docker-compose.yaml. [Quick Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/#install-kompose) to convert your file !!

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that tool and it generates a lot of unnecessary stuff. I thought I convert it correctly and the `command` and `args` are not mandatory to be separated, but the @KFC_ 's answer reveals that I was wrong. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [execute command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod) in the pod you have to define a command in `command` field and arguments for the command in `args` field.  `command` field is the same as `ENTRYPOINT` in Docker and `args` field is the same as `CMD`.
In this case you define `/bin/sh` as ENTRYPOINT and `"-c, "consul agent -server -bootstrap -ui -enable-script-checks=true -client=0.0.0.0 -data-dir=/bitnami/consul/data/ -config-dir=/consul/conf/"` as arguments so it can execute `consul agent ...`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: consul-server
  name: consul-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: consul-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: consul-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: quay.io/bitnami/consul:latest
        name: consul-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8500
        env:
        - name: CONSUL_CONF_DIR # Consul seems not respecting this env variable
          value: /consul/conf/  
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /consul/conf/
        command: ["bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "consul agent -server -bootstrap -ui -enable-script-checks=true -client=0.0.0.0 -data-dir=/bitnami/consul/data/ -config-dir=/consul/conf/"] 
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: consul-config
```

Comment: When I was learning docker I didn't think that separating `command` and `args` is necessary. But now I see it is! I can't imagine how `directory not found` error is related to this separation! Can you explain this, please? :) Thanks!